# Booting to USB drive loads my "broken" Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, boot, usb, ssd

Today my Win7 computer stopped booting. Yesterday it was fine. I determined that the master boot record was corrupt so I created a Win7 bootable USB drive and ran the startup repair utility and allegedly fixed the errors.

I rebooted to the SSD, expecting it to be fixed but I get the same boot errors as before. Then I rebooted to USB to rerun the startup repair but ... my full Windows instance comes up!

The process is repeatable.

- Boot to SSD = no boot media
- Boot to USB = boots full Windows from SSD

What is happening? How do I get my BIOS to boot to the SSD properly?

---

**UPDATE**

I didn't think of this when I originally wrote the question, but now, after doing my investigating, I connected a few dots that seem to be very important. I realized that the root cause of all of this happening is that when I originally installed this copy of Windows, I had had another HDD with another instance of Windows installed on it. The booting must have stopped working when I removed the older HDD, thus removing the MBR for the computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other three answers from jdh, harrymc and masgo all contributed in getting me to solve the issue but since none of them encapsulated everything, I am answering my own question here for others.

Per harrymc's suggestion, I reimaged the USB stick and was able to boot back into Startup Recovery. SR was still not seeing my Windows installation so I couldn't select it to automatically fix it. From there, I went into the command prompt and attempted [jdh's suggested Q&A regarding bootloaders](https://superuser.com/questions/429678/can-not-boot-windows-from-the-main-hard-disk-after-formatting-drive-c-in-ubuntu/429695#429695). So I ran,

```
bootrec.exe /fixmbr
```

...which worked, and then ...

```
bootrec.exe /fixboot
```

... to which I received an error *Element not found*.

I found a [TechNet discussion on this error message](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/7791044e-db7f-4144-a96c-945299811f58/bootmgr-not-found-bootrec-rebuildbcd-and-fixboot-give-element-not-found-error?forum=w7itproinstall) which lists many different solutions for many different people. The one that worked for me was suggested by Kevon Walcott about 14 posts down. He suggested running the following `diskpart` commands in the command prompt to mark the Windows partition as active. One thing that wasn't clear to me in his instructions was which drive and partition you are trying to activate. To clarify, the drive and partition you will be activating is the drive and partition that Windows is installed too.

```
Diskpart
LIST DISK
SELECT DISK (followed by the number of the disk . most likely 0)
LIST PARTITION
SELECT PARTITION (followed by your partition number. most likely 0)
ACTIVE
EXIT
```

From there, I rebooted to Startup repair. Before I could do anything, it recognized that there were boot errors, attempted to fix them and then rebooted. However, my computer still couldn't find the boot media.

So I booted into USB again and, for the first time, SR found my Windows installation. I selected it and started the *Startup Repair*. Once completed, I rebooted again and Windows was up and running, good as new.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me like windows restored the correct MBR to the wrong device (i.e., your USB stick). I would go ahead an use a different tool to restore your MBR. There are a lot of bootable ISOs out there.

For convenience I would recommend you take something like [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) or [YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) and choose one (or more) of the recovery images they offer. I would suggest a simple Linux ISO (like Xubuntu) but depending on your experience you might want to use something else. You should use another USB stick - not the one with the Win7 on it.

What should probably work is to copy the MBR from the Win7 USB-Stick to your HDD.

Final reminder: BACKUP! Since you can boot into your Windows: do a backup of all your (important) data as long as you can. Maybe the reason why your MBR broke in the first place is that your disk is about to fail (or maybe just bad luck). To be sure: do a backup!

Comment: I think this must have been what happened ... startup repair put the MBR on the USB stick. I had already wiped and reimaged the USB stick per harrymc's suggestion so I couldn't try out your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the utility you used did not completely repair the windows 7 boot configuration, just the boot record.
Try these steps in [this answer about repairing your boot loader.](https://superuser.com/questions/429678/can-not-boot-windows-from-the-main-hard-disk-after-formatting-drive-c-in-ubuntu/429695#429695)

Comment: Thanks. That answer didn't actually work, but the errors I received there led me to another article that had the solution. This definitely helped set me on the right path.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to fix the USB boot of Windows, just recreate the USB stick.
Probably something went wrong with it, but rewriting will fix the problem.

The safest action would be to use the Windows 7 boot USB to do a [Repair Install](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html).
This will fix the currently installed Windows 7 while preserving user accounts, data, programs, and system drivers.

Otherwise, here are some products that specialize in correcting boot problems:

[Paragon Rescue Kit Free Edition](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/rk-free/requirements.html)
[boot-repair-disk](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/)

Comment: I think the original start up repair put the MBR on the USB stick. I reimaged it and I had to do another extra step, but this definitely helped set me on the right path.